# B.S. in Electrical Engineering a "Professional Degree"?

Tags: graduate-school, education

You always see those education checkboxes where you pick your level of education; i.e. you have high school diploma, some college, associate, bachelor's, masters/professional, then finally doctorate/professional. Would you check bachelors, masters/professional, or even be able to check doctorate/professional, if it is technically a professional degree? I know this is really more of a technicality, but I'm sure it's best to mark yourself as high as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better term might be "graduate degree." But in this context, "professional degree" would mean "higher than bachelor's."

The main "professional degrees" used to be MD (medical doctor), JD (Juris Doctor or lawyer), and PhD. Later, MBA (Master of Business Adminstration) became popular. So "other"msasters, M.S's or M.A's, could also be "professional degrees."

Yes, B.S. of Electrical Engineering would be a professional degree in the literal sense of the word. But not in the above sense.

Comment: Of course I appreciate the answer, but I must ask, would a master's degree in Electrical Engineering then be a professional degree in the above sense? Professional Engineers are licensed and are definitely more suited to the above meaning of having a professional degree than someone with an MBA.

Comment: @RoryHector: Yes, an M.S. in EE is the equivalent (or better) of an MBA in this regard, and are included in "other"  masters (e.g.M.S.) degrees.